# how to execute dynamic query based on the value of dynamic query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below SP and want to excute `query 3` when the value of `query 2 = 0` `or` `null` and want to return values of `query 1 and query 2/query 3`

When I execute the SP I have a value in `@val1 = 50` but still it is going inside the `if loop` and i want to return only `@val`, `@val1` but i am getting 5 values

```
exec usp_GetDefaultValue 'HQP','home','ConDefault','12345'
```

Results:

HQP: 0  // query 1 HQP: 50 //query 2 @val: 0 @val1: 0 can anybody help me in this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetDefaultValue]

    @Service varchar(20), @LOB varchar(10), @Scenario varchar(20), @Num varchar(10)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @val as int
    DECLARE @val1 as int
    DECLARE    @Value  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE    @DefValue  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    set @Value =  'SELECT '  + @Service + ' from PDetail where LOB = ''' + @LOB  + ''' and Scenario =  ''' + @Scenario + '''  and Number = ''' + @Num + ''' '  -- query 1
    set @DefValue =  'SELECT '  + @Service + ' from PDetail where LOB = ''' + @LOB  + ''' and Scenario =  ''none''  and Number =''none''  and pid = 1'         -- query 2

    exec @val = sp_executesql @Value
    exec @val1 = sp_executesql @DefValue

    if (@val1 = 0 or @val1 = null)  
        begin
            set @DefValue = null
            set @DefValue =  'SELECT '  + @Service + ' from PDetail where LOB = ''' + @LOB  + ''' and Scenario =  ''none''  and pid = 2'               -- query 3
            exec @val1 = sp_executesql @DefValue
        end

    select @val,@val1  -- want to return only two values

END
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Please be specific

Comment: Whenever I see questions like this I always think the main problem is a poor table design/structure.

Comment: @ Jeffrey Wieder: updated the problem i am having.

Comment: Please read Erland Sommarskog's [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). Your code is at risk for SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you change

```
  if (@val1 = 0 or @val1 = null)
```

to

```
  if (@val1 IS NULL or @val1 = 0)
```

Remember that this is SQL, the proper way to check for null is with `IS NULL`